# Unclassifiable statement at (1) when calling a function

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm relatively new to Fortran and I have an assignment to find quadrature weights and points where the points are the zeros of the nth legendre polynomial (found using Newton's method); I made functions to find the value of Pn(x) and P'n(x) to sub into Newton's method.

However when actually using the functions in my quadrature subroutine it comes back with:

```
Coursework2a.f90:44.3:

   x = x - P(n,x)/dP(n,x)
   1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

Does anybody know any reasons why this statement could be classed as unclassifiable?

```
subroutine Quadrature(n)

implicit none
integer, parameter :: dpr = selected_real_kind(15) !Double precision
real(dpr) :: P, dP, x, x_new, error = 1, tolerance = 1.0E-6, Pi = 3.141592 !Define Variables
integer, intent(in) :: n
integer :: i

!Next, find n roots. Start with first guess then iterate until error is greater than some tolerance.

do i = 1,n

    x = -cos(((2.0*real(i)-1.0)/2.0*real(n))*Pi)

    do while (error > tolerance)

        x_new = x

        x = x - P(n,x)/dP(n,x)

        error = abs(x_new-x)


    end do 

    print *, x

end do

end subroutine Quadrature
```

Comment: You are declaring P and dP as variables, that is why the compiler complains.
Where are functions P and dP defined? if they are defined inside a module you simply has to include the `USE module_name` statement

Comment: None of my 3 compilers reported the problem you referenced. Are you sure this is the right code? The old way from the sixties is to use the `external P, dP`. The modern way is to use modules or at least interface blocks.

Comment: BTW if you think `real(dpr) :: Pi = 3.141592` defines pi with double precision accuracy, you are mistaken.

Comment: @credondo That's not actually the case - P and dP are explicitly given a type, but they are not explicitly declared as variables.

Comment: My lecturer told us to define the functions like that (but we havent learnt modules yet). How should i define Pi with double precision Vladimir? I managed to get rid of the error by setting a variable "ratio" = P(n,x)/dP(n,x) and taking that away in newtons method instead, However my first guess seems to keep giving me -1 (well -0.999999917..) and i have no idea why, so i keep finding the same root for each loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
x = -cos(((2.0*real(i)-1.0)/2.0*real(n))*Pi)
```

is likely missing a set of brackets around the denominator. As it is, the line divides `(2.0*real(i)-1.0)` by `2.0`, then multiplies the whole thing by `real(n)`. This may be why you get the same root for each loop.

Comment: Thanks alot Ben Criger

Answer (score -1):

```
real function p(n,x)
real::n,x
p=2*x**3 !or put in the function given to you.
end function

real function dp(n,x)
real::n,x
dp=6*x**2 !you mean derivative of polynomial p, I guess.
end function
```

Define function like this separately outside the main program. Inside the main program declare the functions like:

```
real,external::p, dp
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think the problem in the question is?  The code of the question already has `real(dpr) :: P, dP` which declares the functions `p` and `dp`, so I don't see what you mean.  (I can't speak for the person downvoting, but this may reflect on the fact that few people would ideally recommend using such implicit interfaces.)

Comment: That is fine. But I dont see anywhere in your code how you wrote functions p and dp.